# Error while Updating an existing entity in Nop Commerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I was following the tutorial [Updating an existing entity. How to add a new property](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14424990).

I was able to change the data model successfully. But when I tried to change the presentation model I got following error. How can I fix it?

CategoryValidator:

The changes that I did to source code (presentation).

```
namespace Nop.Admin.Validators.Catalog
{
   public partial class CategoryValidator : BaseNopValidator<CategoryModel>
   {
      public CategoryValidator(ILocalizationService localizationService, IDbContext dbContext)
      {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Catalog.Categories.Fields.Name.Required"));
        RuleFor(x => x.PageSizeOptions).Must(ValidatorUtilities.PageSizeOptionsValidator).WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Catalog.Categories.Fields.PageSizeOptions.ShouldHaveUniqueItems"));

        RuleFor(m => m.SomeNewProperty).Length(0, 255);

        SetStringPropertiesMaxLength<Category>(dbContext);
    }
}
}
```

Catalog Model:

```
namespace Nop.Admin.Models.Catalog
{
  [Validator(typeof(CategoryValidator))]
  public partial class CategoryModel : BaseNopEntityModel, ILocalizedModel<CategoryLocalizedModel>
  {
   //other code not posted in question
  [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Categories.Fields.SomeNewProperty")]
    public string SomeNewProperty { get; set; }
}
}
```

View page:

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         @Html.NopLabelFor(model=> model.SomeNewProperty)
        </div>
       <div class="co-md-9">
          @Html.NopEditorFor(model=>model.SomeNewProperty)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.SomeNewProperty)
        </div>
     </div>
```

Error :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: length

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: length


Source Error: 


Line 414:            htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" };
Line 415:
Line 416:            result.Append(helper.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes }));
Line 417:
Line 418:            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());

Source File: c:\newfolder\nopCommerce\nopCommerce_3.80_Source\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\HtmlExtensions.cs Line: 416 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: length]
    System.Web.Mvc.UnobtrusiveValidationAttributesGenerator.ValidateUnobtrusiveValidationRule(ModelClientValidationRule rule, IDictionary`2 resultsDictionary, String dictionaryKey) +910
       System.Web.Mvc.UnobtrusiveValidationAttributesGenerator.GetValidationAttributes(IEnumerable`1 clientRules, IDictionary`2 results) +135
       System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(String name, ModelMetadata metadata) +265
       System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Object value, Boolean useViewData, Boolean isChecked, Boolean setId, Boolean isExplicitValue, String format, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
+723
       System.Web.Mvc.Html.DefaultEditorTemplates.HtmlInputTemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, String inputType, Object value) +68
```

Comment: I'm not sure what information you need?

Comment: Alright, go to the documentation link and find out this(*//I think this code can speak for itself*) line, and check in your code, you have added `RuleFor(m => m.SomeNewProperty).Length(0, 255);` or not.

Comment: Yes I did add that line

Comment: Okay, could you add that code to the question please.

Comment: Remove this line `RuleFor(m => m.SomeNewProperty).Length(0, 255);` and check.

Comment: I tried different options. Only thing prevented this error is if I remove the `@Html.NopEditorFor..` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` lines

Comment: Set `this.Property(m => m.SomeNewProperty).IsOptional();` instead of `this.Property(m => m.SomeNewProperty).HasMaxLength(255).IsOptional();`

Comment: It worked. If you want I can mark it as answer

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because you were added validation *more than once* of length

Just change this line:

```
this.Property(m => m.SomeNewProperty).HasMaxLength(255).IsOptional();
```

To:

```
this.Property(m => m.SomeNewProperty).IsOptional();
```

Comment: I think the NOP Comm documentation needs to be updated. Thanks for help

Comment: Yeah, I think we can create a request at [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/f/18/nopcommercecom-website.aspx) and ask to change it.